# Accessing property file in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I am creating a simple spring boot application in which I am trying to access an external `config.properties` file.

**IndexController.java**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    XmlOperation xmlOperation = new XmlOperation();

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "btnOpen", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
        try {
            InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
            model.addAttribute("fileContent", xmlOperation.readXml(is));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

**XmlOperation.java**

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class XmlOperation {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public String readXml(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("filepath"));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String fileContent = writer.toString();
        return fileContent;

    }
```

The `config.properties` file is situated in `src/main/resources`. I am not able to get the value from the property file.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `config.properties` file in `src/main/resources` is alright but why do you initialize:

`XmlOperation xmlOperation = new XmlOperation();`

in `IndexController`? And I am also not sure whether `XmlOperation` is spring component (you have only `@PropertySource` over XmlOperation in the question).

Basically I would make `XmlOperation` as a **spring** `@Component` and with IoC inject this component into `IndexController`.

`public String readXml(InputStream is)` in `XmlOperation` behaves like standard service and I would create property `filepath` and inject value from configuration file (`config.properties`) with `@Value` annotation.

---

**FULL EXAMPLE:**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private XmlOperation xmlOperation;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "btnOpen", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
        try {
            InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
            model.addAttribute("fileContent", xmlOperation.readXml(is));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class XmlOperation {

    // use this when XmlOperation is @Configuration bean and you want to create @Bean-s e.g
    // @Autowired
    // Environment env;

    // for your case inject property like this
    @Value("${filepath}")
    private String filepath;

    public String readXml(InputStream is) throws IOException {

        // dont use this
        //System.out.println(env.getProperty("filepath"));

        // rather this
        System.out.println(filepath);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String fileContent = writer.toString();
        return fileContent;

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `@Component`, Can I add `@Service` Annotation?? If no, why?? I am new to spring so it is little difficult to understand the documentation.

Comment: @NewBeeDeveloper If you want to have business methods in XmlOperation you can annotate class as a Service. Component is some kind of generic annotation declares class is managed within spring container.